# How to use Caching in ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, caching, rubygems

My gem will going to call some service to get data based on Parameters given. I want to cache my gem method. I don't know How to implement caching in gem.

Comment: In order to implement caching, you probably need to understand which kind of caching you want and where you are going to cache what.

Comment: I have to cache my method similar to action caching in rails.I am not sure how to configure caching in gem. @SimoneCarletti